# Не доступен setSelection для editText

Tags: java, android

В xml шаблоне у меня имеется EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/edit_cmnt_field"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

В коде я его подключаю:

```
textField = (TextView) findViewById(com.frienddime.frienddime.R.id.edit_cmnt_field);
```

А затем хочу установить курсор в определённую позицию, для этого пишу textField. и начинаю набирать setSelection, но он недоступен, он печатается красным. Я смотрел разные примеры, там есть setSelection и он работает без проблем. Почему же у меня он недоступен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы перепутали тип вашей переменной. В разметке у вас EditText, а в коде TextView, у коего нет такого метода.

Смените класс переменной на EditText

Comment: Точно, как-то я прошляпил) Всё, теперь работает!